# Python Tkinter destroy toplevel window missing argument

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy, toplevel

My Code opens a window with a button. When the button gets clicked a toplevel window is created and the root window gets destroyed. When the button on the toplevel window gets clicked a messagebox opens. I want the the Toplevel Window to be closed when the user presses the ok button of the messagebox.
Pressing Ok causes the TypeError: destroy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I really don't understand why it dosn't work since the toplevel window gets passed as an argument to the destroy method.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Hauptmenü")

    mainmenue(root)

    root.mainloop()


def mainmenue(root):
    button_rennen = tk.Button(root, text="New Window", width=20,
                              command=lambda: call_window(root))
    button_rennen.pack()


def call_window(root):
    root.destroy()
    rframe = tk.Toplevel

    button = tk.Button(text="Wette platzieren",
                            command=lambda: question(rframe))

    button.pack()


def question(rframe):
    dialog = tk.messagebox.askokcancel(message="Destroy Window?")


    if dialog is True:
        rframe.destroy()


main()
```

Comment: Missing `()` in the line `rframe = tk.Toplevel`.

Comment: ```rframe=tk.Toplevel()``` is the correct syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
Using the brackets will result in a blank toplevel window which opens in addition to the intended window. I already tried `rframe = lambda: tk.Toplevel()` but this will cause the AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def call_window(root):
    root.destroy()
    rframe = tk.Tk()

    button = tk.Button(rframe, text="Wette platzieren",
                            command=lambda: question(rframe))

    button.pack()
```

replace toplevel with Tk window and it works fine.

Comment: Please accept it as answer and vote it up 